# Visual studio form design wont appear in C#

Tags: visual-studio

I have BIG problem. I spent hours creating a form and yesterday. I do not know what happened or what I clicked on but when I ran the program to see if my code works. the form was completely GONE. Every button, datagrid was gone.

So I thought I have to start again? but wait, the buttons and datagrid and labels I used apparently already existed. My code is still the same. I think it might be the

```
  InitializeComponent();
```

I am not sure. WHY did this happen. HOW can I get my previous design back, is it possible? The code I used before was exactly the same. The code did not get deleted.

Thank you

Comment: If the InitializeComponent exists with all the declarations and initializations of your UI elements then did you check if this method is called in the Form constructor?

Comment: I don't know if it exists with all the declarations and initializations but it exists in the constructor